# Using multiple criteria with Select

Tags: filtering

Suppose I have this list of strings...

```
test = {"abc", "abcdef", "ghi", "jkl"}
```

...and wish to filter it, selecting only those strings that have length = 3, contain the letters f, i, or k, and don't contain the letter g.  I can accomplish this in succession, as follows:

```
Select[test, StringLength[#] == 3 &]
Select[%, StringContainsQ[{"f", "i", "k"}]]
Select[%, StringFreeQ["g"]]
```

> {"abc", "ghi", "jkl"}

> {"ghi", "jkl"}

> {"jkl"}

However, I'd prefer to accomplish this in one step, which would require `Select` to take multiple criteria.

According to an example in the documentation, `Select` can do this:

```
Select[Range[100], Mod[#, 3] == 1 && Mod[#, 5] == 1 &]
```

> {1, 16, 31, 46, 61, 76, 91}

However, when I try this with my argument and criteria, it doesn't seem to work:

```
Select[test, StringLength[#] == 3 & && StringContainsQ[{"f", "i", "k"}] && StringFreeQ["g"]]
```

> {}

Is `Select` unable to take multiple criteria when filtering strings rather than numbers, or is there something basic I'm getting wrong?

Comment: The operator form should act on an explicit variable and so it works `Select[test, 
 StringLength[#] == 3 && StringContainsQ[{"f", "i", "k"}]@# && 
   StringFreeQ["g"]@# &]
`

Comment: Or you could use `Through` (you should only use one logical operator like `&&` or other forms, no mixing) `Select[test, Through[(StringLength[#] == 3 & && StringContainsQ[{"f", "i", "k"}] && StringFreeQ["g"])[#]] &]`

Comment: "I'd prefer to accomplish this in one step". I think multiple steps is much more clear and more maintainable. If you look at it 3 weeks later, you still can understand what it is doing.   I do not understand why so many like to put so much logic into one command which makes it hard to understand.

Comment: @Nasser This is clearly a case of à chacun son goût. The main reason I prefer it this way is that it's a lot easier for me to tell what's going on within a notebook if I can see as much code as possible on a single screen, rather than seeing a smaller fragment and having to scroll up and down. The latter demands more memory bandwidth from me. Suppose, e.g., that you have 10 of these. If the inputs are each a single line, I can typically see all the inputs and outputs on one screen. There's not the case if I format them your way, since then I'd have 10 paragraphs of input instead of 10 lines.

Comment: `Select[test, StringLength[#] == 3 && StringContainsQ[#, {"f", "i", "k"}] && StringFreeQ[#, "g"] &]`